# where can I find a description of *all* MIPS instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, instruction-set, mips32

Does anyone know of a web site where I can find a list of 32-bit MIPS instructions/opcodes, with the following features:

- Clearly distinguishes between real opcodes and assembly-language macros (pseudo-instructions)
- Describes the instruction behavior including differences depending on privilege level.

  Indicates in which instruction set revision the instruction was introduced/revised (e.g. MIPS I, MIPS II, MIPS32, etc.)

  Includes privileged instructions such as syscall.

I am aware of numerous web sites which document "part of" the instruction set, mostly for teaching purposes.  They tend to leave out or only partially describe floating-point and privileged instructions.

In case you're wondering, I'm looking at Verilog code for a MIPS processor subset, and trying to figure out exactly to what extent it complies with the instruction sets of any real MIPS processors!

Comment: `syscall` transfers control to supervisor, but does not itself require privileges to execute, that of course being the point.  I'm not sure MIPS IV (the manual I searched) had any instructions that always require privileges, or maybe that's because the MIPS IV manual I looked at says it only defines user-mode instructions.  (But they may all be implemented as System Control Processor (same as coprocessor 0?) operations, not real CPU instructions.  CoProc 0 access from user-mode depends on another bit setting, apparently, from a quick search on on "privilege".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only partially answer the question: I'd recommend [See MIPS Run](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120884216) by Dominic Sweetman, if you're not already referring to it. I have the first edition of the book, the second edition is now current.

- table 8.2 lists each opcode and expected behavior, differentiating assembler macros and  listing the instructions they decompose to. Unfortunately it does not differentiate user vs kernel mode.
- table 8.6 lists the ISA level where each instruction was introduced, including obscure variants like the LSI MiniRISC
- syscall is present in the table, though lacking much description

The first edition mentions the kernel. supervisor, and user privilege levels but does not discuss what operations are allowed in each. I do not know what changes were made in the second edition.

Comment: Thank you, Denton!  This is the best MIPS book ever... unfortunately it's very in-demand from the university library :-(  Hopefully I'll be able to make some photocopies when I can get it checked out.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I found something!

MIPS offers a set of "MIPS 32 reference manuals" which refer to the latest, standardized instruction set (MIPS32v2): [here](http://www.mips.com/products/product-materials/processor/mips-architecture/)

These include just about everything, except the information about which version the instructions originated in :-(

WAIT A SEC...

[This class website at Cornell](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/) includes links to what **appears** to be the same manual, but is in fact an *older version of it*, and [volume 2](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/MIPS_Vol2.pdf) of that older version does in fact include information about when the instructions where first introduced.  Woohoo!

Why would MIPS remove this information from the revised documentation?  There doesn't seem to be any explanation in the revision history.

Comment: That's cool, but be aware that MIPS32R2 does not encompass all the variants that have gone before.

Comment: In hopes to sell you their latest CPU most likely. To make it harder to use older CPUs.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't include instruction descriptions, but the source of the GNU assembler is probably as detailed as you can get regarding what instructions are available on what specific CPUs.

Get [binutils](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils) and look at opcodes/mips-*.c

Comment: Sweet, thanks a ton!!  That is exactly what I need: http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/opcodes/mips-opc.c?rev=1.70&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=src  Includes detailed info on which instructions are in which revisions of the ISA.

Answer (score 1):

The current instruction-set reference manual is free online: [MIPS® Architecture for Programmers
Volume II-A: The MIPS32® Instruction
Set Manual](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-mips/documents/MD00086-2B-MIPS32BIS-AFP-6.06.pdf).  That link is Revision 6.06
December 15, 2016. (i.e. it documents [MIPS32 Release 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32.2FMIPS64_Release_6)).

It documents all user and supervisor/kernel mode instructions, and all floating-point, in full detail including their machine-code encoding, and with an Operation section that shows what they do.  It still documents all the instructions that were removed in MIPS32 release 6.  (MIPS32 Release 6 also moved around a lot of opcodes, and this is well documented).

---

See https://www.mips.com/products/architectures/mips32/ for the latest version.  mips.com has a section for "classic cores", but that still appears to only go back to MIPS32, not historical stuff.

---

Sample of the "availability and compatibility" section for `balc` (Branch and Link Compact: no branch-delay slot, and GRP31 is the implicit destination, freeing up 26 bits for an `offset<<2`):

> This instruction is introduced by and required as of Release 6.
> Release 6 instruction `BALC` occupies the same encoding as pre-Release 6
> instruction `SWC2`. The `SWC2` instruction has been moved to the `COP2`
> major opcode in MIPS Release 6

Or for `LDXC1 fd, index(base)`  (Load Doubleword Indexed to Floating Point)

> This instruction has been removed in Release 6.
> Required in all versions of MIPS64 since MIPS64 Release 1. Not available in MIPS32 Release 1. Required in
> MIPS32 Release 2 and all subsequent versions of MIPS32. When required, required whenever FPU is present,
> whether a 32-bit or 64-bit FPU, whether in 32-bit or 64-bit FP Register Mode (FIRF64=0 or 1, StatusFR=0 or 1).

---

**For historical stuff, I found the [MIPS IV Instruction Set
Revision 3.2
September, 1995](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15740-f97/public/doc/mips-isa.pdf)** on a cmu.edu web page.  It lists when instructions were introduced, e.g. MIPS I for `div`, MIPS III for `dmult` and other 64-bit instructions, MIPS II for `ll` / `sc`.

---

**A good quick-reference with pseudocode** for the effect of each instruction is [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html).  It doesn't include encoding details, but does accurately describe the effect of branch and jump instructions on the program counter.  (Which is somewhat tricky: they're relative or section-absolute to the branch-delay slot.)

It's not complete even for MIPS I integer instructions, though: it's missing the unaligned-load helper instructions LWL and LWR and corresponding SWL/R stores which were present in MIPS I.  It also doesn't include any FP stuff, or later MIPS instructions like `mul` (only `mult`).  I don't know what else might be missing; I didn't cross reference it against a complete list.

The MIPS-IV manual linked above confirms that `lwl`/`lwr` were available in MIPS I (and documents that the load delay slot restriction applies to them).

Answer (score 0):

This [web site (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111203150/http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) describes most of the MIPS instruction set and their encoding.  It's not complete, though: missing at least `nor` and maybe other things.

A good quick-reference with pseudocode for the effect of each instruction is [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html).  It doesn't include encoding details.

The [MIPS](http://www.mips.com/products/processors/32-64-bit-cores/mips32-4ke/index.cfm#resources) web site also has technical documents about the various cores.
For example, I downloaded the manual for the MIPS 4KE core (document #MD00103) "MIPS32® 4KE™ Processor Core Family Software User’s Manual" and chapter 10 contains a detailed description of the Instruction Set.
Note that you have to register to access the documents.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that one seems to only describe the limited subset offered by the SPIM simulator.

Comment: Yeah, http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html isn't complete.  It's at least missing `nor`, I remember noticing when wondering how MIPS did `~x` efficiently.  And BTW, it's finally gone 404, after being google's favourite hit for a long time.  https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_help.html is a good quick-reference.